# VM on GCP Lost network after set static ip in ifcfg-eth0

Tags: networking, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

CentOs 7 with whm
Compute Engine VM Instance was working fine and GCP given external static ip xx.135 and internal 10.xx.x.2

Upon checking it is found that network settings was DHCP hence I 
modified `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0` with `BOOTPROTO=static` with static ip given by GCP and restart network service. After that I lost the 
control of VM. What is wrong? How to resolve the issues and get the control?

Comment: following details was written in ifcfg-eth0
IPADDR=
BROADCAST=
GATEWAY=
NETMASK=

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you needed to modify the DHCP configuration. You could follow [the link here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address) for Reserving a Static External IP Address. Also, this is [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-internal-ip-address) if you would like to Reserve a Static Internal IP Address.

The way to fix a messed up config like this is to use [the console](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console), where the user can revert that config. Just to note here that you might have to have set the password. This is, in fact, one way.

Another way is if the disk attached is a Persistent Disk, you could attach it somewhere else and replace the config. Here is [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-ssh#inspect_an_instance_without_shutting_it_down) for that. There is a caution, some types of VMs that won't allow for this. It won't work if it's a [local SSD](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/#localssds).